# how to let long text change to multiple lines when adding annotation to images

Tags: annotations, dm-script

how to let long text change to multiple lines when adding annotation to image
and make the length of each line are equal, like rectangle?

```
image temp:=getfrontimage()

temp.ShowImage()
imageDisplay disp = front.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
getsize(temp,x,y)
le=x*2/3  
to1=y*80/100
component text1 = NewTextAnnotation(le,to1,string1+","+string2+","+string3,100)
```

I tried to add 3 strings to an image, each string has more than 15 letters/characters, Total more than 50 letters.

If I put all 3 strings in one text annotation in on line, it is too long.

If I put them as 3 text annotations,  as the each line does not have exactly same numbers of letters, it shows ugly.

Is there any could let the text as multiple line, and the background of texts in each line has the same length?

Or the 3 text annotations has the same length, I mean the background of the texts has the same length, when the letters in each text annotations are not same, for example, 1st text annotation with 16 letters, 2nd text annotation with 20 letters, 3rd text annotation with 14 letters, but their background of the text have the same length.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> You can add line-breaks as with all strings by simply adding the line-break escape string `\n`.

Example script:

```
number sx = 512
number sy = 512
image img := RealImage("test",4,sx,sy)
img = icol
img.ShowImage()

imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
number l = sx * 2/3  
number t = sy * 80/100
String mLstr = "Some text line\nSome more text lines\nShort text"
number fontSize = 12

Component Line = disp.NewTextAnnotation(l,t,mLstr,fontSize)
Line.TextAnnotationSetAlignment(1)      // 1=Left, 2=Center, 3=Right
Line.ComponentSetDrawingMode(1)         // 1=with background, 2=without background
Line.ComponentSetBackgroundColor(0.5,0.0,0)
Line.ComponentSetForegroundColor(0,1,0)
disp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd(line)
```

A note: When creating the new component, there are two different variants of the `NewTextAnnotation` command:

```
Component NewTextAnnotation( Component ref_par_comp, Number left, Number top, String text, Number size )
Component NewTextAnnotation( Number left, Number top, String text, Number size )
```

The first one takes the addtional "parent" component. If you use that one, then the font-size will scale with the default display-size of the parent component on the screen, i.e. will not be different for differently sizes images.

To test: Just try the above script with `sx` and `sy` values. Then do the same without the `disp.` in the line-annotation creating line.

Comment: Thanks,  What I should put for "Component ref_par_comp" in using Component NewTextAnnotation( Component ref_par_comp, Number left, Number top, String text, Number size )?For example,  Component NewTextAnnotation( Component ref_par_comp, 3, 3, "hello", 12 ) or ?

Comment: @together see the example above. The parent component, I.e. the component that will hold the annotation. In most cases - such as above - the imageDisplay (which is also a component)